# Chrome not using VPN DNS (Everything else is)

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

DNS in chrome is not using my VPN DNS:

1. Things that should match private vpn DNS records are instead resolving again a public wildcard address
2. This only seems to happen in Chrome, iterm pings and firefox resolve correctly
3. clearing the host cache via `chrome://net-internals/#dns` doesn't
   help, not does clear all cache via settings. Restarting Chrome also
   doesn't seem to help
4. Going to a website via IP in Chrome works fine

Answer (score 9):

For some reason using the "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" was not selecting my VPN DNS servers. I could see that the VPN DNS server was not being used via `chrome://net-internals/#dns`. As a workaround, I disabled this via `chrome://flags`:

[image]

Comment: FYI: This is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265970

Comment: The "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" flag was removed from Google Chrome, thereby disabling the "fix" for this. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/eabf1f5baba38d46921acd6edda594f942f7d6a1

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue right now on 2022-02-17, the "Async DNS Resolver" is no longer available as a flag in `chrome://flags`.

Up to now, I've been having to connect to the VPN and then restart Chrome, but that's not convenient.

But I found a workaround: go to Settings -> Security and privacy -> Security -> Use secure DNS

Then disable "Use secure DNS". After that, Chrome was able to resolve using the VPN DNS.

Comment:  disabling secure dns still did the trick in 2023 - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Async DNS Resolver.
In Chrome for Android, go to `chrome://flags`.
Search for "Async DNS Resolver", and disable it.

Comment: @bertieb Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: I don't see that flag in chrome://flags, can it still be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue through settings, under privacy and settings, there is a section called use secure dns, this forces network activity to googles dns servers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).